# How to write Regex for extracting tags?

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract all tags in a xml file. However, I cannot write proper regular expression to extract the content I want.

The tags format in the file is like :

```
 Tags=<"tracffic""apple""sample">
```

And I want to return a list contained all the tags: [traffic, apple, sample]

I tried this:

```
    Tags=<("[\w]+")+
```

which only return the last tag.

Could anyone give me a hand?

Comment: Are you sure this is xml? Can you post a sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
m = re.search('<(".+")>', 'Tags=<"traffic""apple""sample">')
tags = [x for x in m.group(1).split('"') if x]
```

Now `tags` contains:

```
['traffic', 'apple', 'sample']
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think of the way to split the whole string after matching. :)